# Can I use a stylus on my HP Omni 10 Tablet?

Tags: stylus

I bought a HP Omni 10 (with Corning Gorilla Glass and Windows 8.1), and I want to use a stylus.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The HP Omni 10 seems to be using a [capacitive touch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkGgg.jpg). Therefore, as long as your stylus is compatible with capacitive touch screens, like the iPad or similar, it should work with your tablet.

Generally, a stylus will say on the packaging or in the specifications that it works with capacitive screens. Worst case, go to your local electronics store and ask to try one.

Capacitive styluses generally have that squishy tip, like this:

[image]